# push numbers that repeats only 2 times in sequence in a new array

Tags: javascript, arrays, math, methods

I want my array puma to contain 2,3,5,7,13,17,19,23 at the end of the code. (They are the ones that repeat 02 times in sequence in the number array) Thanks

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Trial</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script>
      var number = [1,2,2,3,3,4,4,4,5,5,6,6,6,6,7,7,8,8,8,8,
                    9,9,9,10,10,10,10,10,11,12,12,12,12,12,12,
                    12,13,13,14,14,14,14,14,15,15,15,15,15,
                    16,16,16,16,16,17,17,18,18,18,18,18,18,
                    18,18,19,19,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,21,
                    21,21,21,22,22,22,22,23,23];
      var puma=[];
      for (k=0; k<number.length; k++)
        for (i=1; i<number.length; i++) 
          for (j=2; j<number.length; j++) 
          {
            if (number[k]==number[i] && number[k]!==number[j])
            {
              puma.push(number[k]);
            }
          };

      document.write(puma);
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Do you mean odd numbers or simply unique values ? ?

Comment: @Neta I want these as results 2,3,7,13,17,19,23

Comment: What if we have this array: `[2, 2, 0, 0, 2, 2, 2]` ? Should result be `[0]` or `[0, 2]` ?

Comment: That's a good question, but my data is distributed in sequence so there's no chance to find 2,2,2 if I already had 2,2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `counting sorting` concept for this purpose. So we can firstly count number of each element. And then get elements whose count is equal to two.

```js
var number = [1,2,2,3,3,4,4,4,5,5,6,6,6,6,7,7,8,8,8,8,9,9,9,10,10,10,10,10,11,12,12,12,12,12,12,12,13,13,14,14,14,14,14,15,15,15,15,15,16,16,16,16,16,17,17,18,18,18,18,18,18,18,18,19,19,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,21,21,21,21,22,22,22,22,23,23],
    counts = [],
    puma=[],
    i;

for(i = 0; i < number.length; i++) {
    counts[number[i]] = !!counts[number[i]] ? counts[number[i]] + 1 : 1;
}

function getNumbers(counts, n) {
    return counts.reduce(function(a, c, i) {
        if(c === n) {
            a.push(i);
        }
        return a;
    }, []);
}


document.write(getNumbers(counts, 2) + '</br>');
document.write(getNumbers(counts, 3) + '</br>');
document.write(getNumbers(counts, 4));
```

#### Update

If it is needed to get numbers only by sequences, then we have two possible situations:

1. When there is only one sequence and its length = N
2. When there are several sequences and length of one of them is equal N.

```js
var number = [0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1],
    counts = [],
    puma=[],
    prev, i, currentCount = 1;

for(i = 1, prev = number[0]; i < number.length; i++) {
 var current = number[i];
 
 if(prev === current) {
  currentCount++;
 }
 
 if(prev !== current || i === number.length - 1) {
  console.log(prev)
  counts[prev] = (counts[prev] || []).concat([currentCount]);
  prev = current;
  currentCount = 1;
 }
}

// (2nd situation) Get every number if it was found N times in a sequence
function getNumbers1(counts, n) {
    return counts.reduce(function(a, c, i) {
        if(c.indexOf(n) > -1) {
            a.push(i);
        }
        return a;
    }, []);
}

// (1st situation) Get number only if there is only one sequence of this number and it's length is equal to N
function getNumbers2(counts, n) {
    return counts.reduce(function(a, c, i) {
        if(c.length === 1 && c[0] === n) {
            a.push(i);
        }
        return a;
    }, []);
}

document.write(getNumbers1(counts, 2) + '</br>');
document.write(getNumbers2(counts, 2));
```

In this code we firstly get all the lengths of every sequence of every number. And then get the sequences that we need.
In last example `counts` array will be equal to `[ [ 2 ], [ 2, 3 ], [ 1 ] ]` after

Comment: doesn't check sequencing ... only totals. May not work depending on OP input can be sorted or not or in more certain terms...would have to sort OP input

Comment: that's going to work perfectly and is exactly the the OP wanted

Comment: @NetaMeta put an extra one of those numbers at end of array and it doesn't have same output due to total count vs sequence count. OP did ask for sequence count. I'm not saying this won't work but also depends on OP constraints which aren't well defined

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/152r15ny/1/ works perfectly fine same sequence - and as expected - maybe give an example to demonstrate your point ?

Comment: @yuriy I want to be able to navigate within my array. I mean what if I want to do the same thing with numbers that appears only 03 times? result (4,9) and later with numbers that appears only 4 times?

Comment: This algorithm does absolutely nothing about "2 times in a sequence" part of the OP's condition. Using this algorithm even an array like `[2,3,7,13,17,19,23,2,3,7,13,17,19,23]` will produce the same result.

Comment: @yuriy it's perfect. Now I just need some explanation about the line of code underneath the for loop. I had never seen a js method like this  counts[number[i]] = !!counts[number[i]] ? counts[number[i]] + 1 : 1;

Comment: @s.purpose, `!!` is used for type casting to boolean. So we are checking if `counts[number[i]]` is `true`. It could also be written this way: `counts[number[i]] == true` or  simply `counts[number[i]]` because JS will cast type to boolean itself in ternary operator (So `!!` is used only for clarity). Then ternary operator is used: `exp1 ? expr2 : expr3`, which means that if `expr1` is true then evaluate expr2, in another case evaluate expr3. This all statement we can read this way: If `counts[number[i]]` is defined then assign `counts[number[i]] + 1`, and if its undefined assign 1 to it.